# IE not toggling from list item trigger

Tags: jquery, html, internet-explorer

jQuery:

```
$( '#mainNavSidebar .subListTrigger' ).click( function(){
    $( this ).next( '.subList' ).toggle();
});
```

HTML:

```
<style>.subList{ display: none; }</style>
<ul id="mainNavSidebar">
    <li class="subListTrigger">
        <a>About Us</a>
    </li>
    <ul class="subList">
        <li><a>Welcome</a></li>
        <li><a>Mission</a></li>
    </ul>
</ul>
```

So I'm stuck using an older version of jQuery which is why I'm using click() instead of on().  But this is working fine in Chrome and Firefox, but it does nothing in IE.  If I put an alert in there it will do that, so I think the problem is with either the next() or the toggle().  Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: It might help to know WHICH version please.

Comment: your `a` tags are not valid as posted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your HTML is invalid, IE is most likely fixing it for you in a way that breaks the code.

Make your html valid.

```
<style>.subList{ display: none; }</style>
<ul id="mainNavSidebar">
    <li class="subListTrigger">
        <a>About Us</a>
        <ul class="subList"> <!-- the only valid child of a ul is a li -->
            <li><a>Welcome</a></li>
            <li><a>Mission</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

..

```
$( '#mainNavSidebar .subListTrigger' ).click( function(){
    $( '.subList', this ).toggle();
});
```

Comment: You may add that `ul`s are not valid direct descendants (children) of `ul`. Oh I see the updated comment now.

Comment: Congrats on the catch! Didn't see that one :)

Comment: @FabrícioMatté Oops, i think i added that shortly after.

Comment: oh I see, because I'm using a ul inside of a ul without wrapping it in a li.  Thanks, that totally did the trick

Comment: Though I believe the trigger should be in a different `li` than the `subList`, this looks like some kind of accordion. With the sub-list as a descendant of the trigger, a click in the sub-list will trigger the `toggle`.